# Ok as a YouTuber I wish to make a animation that features darth maul and Vader am I allowed to use the original design or do I have to majorly alter

Tags: united-states

Am I able to use the original maul design can I minorly alter it or do I have to majorly change his design

Comment: For future reference, when posting on Stack Exchange sites, it's best to have the title of your question be concise and grammatical.  You don't need words like "ok", and proper nouns should be capitalized.  And your title is really two sentences - even if it weren't a run-on, shorter would be better. So for instance, "Can I use Star Wars characters in a YouTube animation?"  Even if you're typing on a phone, it is worth spending a few more seconds because it greatly increases your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Copyright has no "change it enough so the teacher doesn't notice" clause. If it's a derivative work, it's a derivative work.

Comment: Change the question from being about you the being about a fictional YouTuber named “Bob” and it can be reopened because then you won’t be asking for legal advice.  Yes, that’s how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

Copyright includes the exclusive right to create derivative works. So "majorly changing" the design will not get you around any accusations of copyright infringement. What you would have to do is to create a design from scratch.

And as Trish said, I don't know who owns the originals, but if it is Disney, they *will* sue you and it will cost you much more money than you can afford. Whether they win their case or not.

Comment: Darth Vader/Maul are from Star Wars, owned by by Lucasfilm, which was fully acquired by Disney in 2012. You *do* not mention the Fair use (which would make this perfect).